# Запись списка кортежей побайтово в файл

Tags: python, файлы

Есть список пар чисел <= 10**9.

```
l = [(0, 15), (3, 48)]
```

Как записать их в файл в байтовом виде, чтобы на каждый элемент списка в итоге было по 8 байт? Т.е. размер итоговый:

```
len(l) * (4 + 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, примерно так:

```
import os.path

l = [(0, 15), (3, 48)]

with open('file.txt', 'wb') as f:
    for (a, b) in l:
        f.write(a.to_bytes(4, 'big'))
        f.write(b.to_bytes(4, 'big'))

print(len(l) * (4 + 4))
# 16

print(os.path.getsize('file.txt'))
# 16
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [(0, 15), (3, 48)]

with open('file.txt', 'wb') as f:
    for (a, b) in l:
        f.write(a.to_bytes(4, 'big') + b.to_bytes(4, 'big'))
    
    f.write(b'\n')
```

Попробовал так, всё получилось, спасибо gil9red.

Comment: `f.write(b'\n')` а зачем новую строку писать?

Comment: @gil9red всё правильно, неверно размер посчитал итоговый

Comment: Хорошо, примите мой ответ :)

Comment: Кст, и лучше удалите ответ, т.к. по сути это не ответ, а ваше уточнение по моему ответу

Comment: @gil9red это теперь будет проблематично, потому что юзер зачем-то создал второй аккаунт

Comment: @andreymal, интересно девки пляшут... :D